# How to check if particular text already exists in a csv file using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check if particular text already exists in a csv file.

Is there any way or function except storing the whole file into variable and comparing each of its contents with the target text?

Comment: Something has to open the file to read it at some stage. What exactly are you trying to avoid? Why not just open the file, read it’s contents and look for the strings in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about checking for delimiters, etc. and (importantly) you never need to search for text that contains a newline, you could use `File.ReadLines` and `.Contains` to check for a specific text:

```
string fileName = "myFile.csv";
string textToFind = "bob";
bool hasText = File.ReadLines(fileName)
    // .Skip(1) // uncomment this line if your file has a header you wish to skip
    .Any(l => l.Contains(textToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

You can change `StringComparison.Ordinal` to `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` if you want a case insensitive search.

`File.ReadLines` reads the file line-by-line as `.Any` is evaluated, so you don't have to load the entire file into memory in one go, and `.Any` will exit early if a match is found, so the file will stop being read at that point.

Note that for older versions of .NET, `.Contains` doesn't have an overload that takes a `StringComparison` so in that case you can only use `.Any(l => l.Contains(textToFind));`

Comment: yes this is the correct answer. You can also use a regex to match your string if the pattern is not so simple.

Comment: @ProgrammingLIama   I get the following error while using your approach......Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @shital Any is a LINQ extension method. You need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file. If you click Any and press Ctrl+. On the keyboard, it will prompt you to add the using.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ReadAllText function and use regex or find to check exist particular text

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example? Also, this seems to go against OP's wish to avoid loading the entire file into memory.